# I do not remember my oracle system password

Tags: oracle

I have watched many YouTube videos about how to unlock the password of an Oracle instance, where the user has forgotten there password. In these videos the DBAs used the additional command `sys as dba` as the username and then did not have to enter any password.

Once they pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it showed them a `sql >` prompt, with which they could then alter the password(s), but when I follow these steps, it shows me the following error message:

> error, ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possibly add the OS you are using and a short overview of the environment you are running? The options to overcome your issue may vary from OS (Windows) to OS (Linux). Hit the [edit] link in this comment or just below your question and add more details. Thanks for taking your time to add details so that the community can assist in solving your problem. Good luck!

Comment: ORA-12560 is almost always due to improper setting of the environment variable ORACLE_SID.  Of course, we have no way of knowing exactly, because you failed to show us 1) what OS you are on, 2) _exactly_ what you entered at the command line, 3) what OS user you were logged on as

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set ORACLE_SID to the database instance name, in my example it is `XE`.
Your Windows user needs to be a member of local group "`ORA_DBA`".

So, now you do not connect to the database by username and password.
Instead `"/"` indicates authentication by the Operating System as sys user.

```
C:\>set ORACLE_SID=XE
C:\>REM login as the database root account "sys"
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL>alter user system account unlock;
SQL>exit
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

You need to be logged on to your OS as the Oracle user, then connecting "/ as sysdba" may work.